# What is the easiest migration path for db.model when I am adding new required fields?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have such data stored in database:

```
class DeleteMe(db.model):
        value1 = IntegerProperty(required = True, indexed = False)
```

And want to migrate it to such schema:

```
class DeleteMe(db.model):
        value1 = IntegerProperty(required = True, indexed = False)
        value2 = IntegerProperty(required = True, indexed = False)
```

What is the easiest method to migrate?

I found that I can do this in such way but it slow and error generating.

First create new table without required:

```
class DeleteMe(db.model):
        value1 = IntegerProperty(required = True, indexed = False)
        value2 = IntegerProperty(required = False, indexed = False)
```

Second update all records.

Third switch target model with required:

```
class DeleteMe(db.model):
        value1 = IntegerProperty(required = True, indexed = False)
        value2 = IntegerProperty(required = True, indexed = False)
```

It is slow so I think that I am not doing it correctly or app engine not allows it? Please help to find good way.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do all that. You simply add the new required field and update all the records that don't have the `value2` with a default value. Your application will work without any issues for the entities that don't have the `value2` initialized.

I would suggest you to add a default value, if possible to have it, so in case you will update other values in the entity without touching the `value2` the application will not crash.

Also don't forget that if you don't update the old entities (by explicitly editing and storing the value) even if you'll have set the default value if you query on the `value2` the old entities won't be included in the result.

Comment: Do you mean that I must add default value for new required field to avoid problem?

Comment: Do you mean that ... (as previous) ...?

Comment: @Chameleon Not entirely sure what you mean by this question.. I think all you have to do is to add this new property and experiment..! With or without default value... with or without required.. :) What I'm saying is that you don't need to go through the process that you mentioned.. you can simply add new properties as you wish!! If you need default values add them.. if it needs to be required.. add it and then go through all of them and add a value to them.. since it's required I'm guessing you need a value in it..! :)

Comment: I seek clear answer if you not check if is not answer I can check.